# System fails to boot new kernel after CentOS 9 Stream migration

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, grub2, grub2-mkconfig

I have performed a migration from `CentOS 8 Stream` to `Centos 9 Stream` on a VPS server of mine with directions I found [on Github](https://gist.github.com/yodermk/9c8081a70ec4e0f2ffca8d6c3603da32) which have worked, except grub still boots the old kernel from when the system ran CentOS 8 Stream. I have tried reinstalling the kernel package which should update grub itself and I have also tried upgrading grub.

I tried the kernel reinstall with this command...

```
# dnf reinstall kernel
```

I also tried to update the grub configuration file, which normally will list the kernels in `/boot` that it puts in the configuration...

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

I also tried the above with `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg` but the output was the same.

Here is the generated `grub.cfg` file from this, which clearly has no kernels listed in it: https://dpaste.com/ATGL8C523

These are the vmlinuz files in /boot and show the new kernel is there, and there are other files in this directory as well such as initramfs, etc...

```
/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-a5ff5996dcd8490680008260ff7a2d2f
/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-f6af4a0f32be46729879177156b19b96
/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64
/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-394.el8.x86_64
/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-109.el9.x86_64
```

The system has booted with the old kernel from CentOS 8 as shown in the output for `uname -sr`...

```
4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64
```

Here is the configuration for `/etc/default/grub` on the system...

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

The server is a VPS I lease which runs KVM using Proxmox as the hypervisor.

Comment: `man grub2-set-default` or delete `/boot/grub2/grubenv`

Comment: The new kernel is literally not even in the menu, after recreating the `grub.cfg` with `grub2-mkconfig` it finds no kernels and so there are no menu items to set as default.

Comment: Deleting `/boot/grub2/grubenv` has had no effect and running `grub2-mkconfig` still doesn't detect the kernels in `/boot`.

Comment: RHEL9 uses BLSCFG with entries defined in `/boot/loader/entries`, not in `grub.cfg`. This file is now or more less immutable. `grub2-mkconfig` shouldn't even detect any kernels, it's not its job. Rerunning `grub2-mkconfig` in RHEL9 makes no sense, as it will generate the exact same file all the time.

Comment: Thanks, it boots.